# How to add status bar in Qt5.3.1

Tags: qt5

I am developing small application in Qt5.3.1 in win 7. 
I removed status bar from mainwindow and found that 
there is no widget named status bar. Please tell
me how to add status bar dynamically or from IDE Qt Designer.

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the form and click `Create Status Bar`:

[image]